# sed, to delete some numbers of lines after match

Tags: bash, sed

sed can delete some numbers of lines after match with match

```
sed -e /regexp/,+<number_of_lines>
```

but how delete in addition to this yet 10th line for example

UPDATE

Well not really the exact question.

Need to delete second, third, fourth and 6th lines after match and match itself

Comment: is `sed` a must? also, only the next 10th line or every 10th lines?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have `GNU sed` you can do `sed '/regexp/,+10d' file` to delete the 10 lines after *(and including)* the match. You can do `sed '/regexp/,+4d;10d' file` to delete the 4 line after *(and including)* the match plus the 10th line.

Comment: What about BSD sed?